# unable to install python pdfinterp with pip cammand

Tags: python

when i am installing some module like  pdfinterp with  pip command   gives below error please share any solution.
 **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip**

Comment: What is the pip command you are using?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you are trying to install the pdfinterp module, which is a part of the pdfminer package.

So, to properly install pdfinterp, you would need to run:

`sudo -H pip install pdfminer`

However, pdfminer is only for Python2.7! You don't specify in your question, but if you are using Python3.6, you would need to run:

`sudo -H pip3 install pdfminer3k`

Which downloads [pdfminer3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k), a "Python 3 port of pdfminer" which should mean your pdfinterp module should be downloaded with.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Before we begin, try upgrading your `pip` package by running:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

(Or `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` on Windows)

This will ensure your pip packages are up-to-date.

Then, according to [errors reported](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1549) on the pip GitHub repo concerning `pdfminer`, you should be able to run the install explained in the original answer above. The reason this error is occurring for you is because at one time [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme) was having issues with the declaration of "prerelease detection logic":

> I'm guessing pip was confused by the old N[.N]+ spelling in the PEP,
>   that got clarified in recent editions to N(.N)*. [SOURCE](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1549)

This should fix the issue, if you still have problems comment below with the error it returns and we can go from there!

Here is some additional information about the issue that was raised in error [#1555](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1555) of PyPa pip's GitHub Repo.

As a side note, my machine is running the most recent version of pip and is fully functioning with `pdfminer` and `pdfminer3k`!

Comment: Python version is 2.7.12+ .Still i am unable to insall  pdfminer.

Comment: Do you get any error messages with the pip install statements above? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes I got following message--Collecting pdfminer
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pdfminer (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pdfminer

Comment: pip already up-to-date .still showing same error as previously came

Comment: Do you have Python3 on your machine at all, or only 2.7?

Comment: Python 2.7.12+ only